# emv APDU response 6581. lock VISA card?

Tags: credit-card, apdu, emv

I have some experiment with my emv card (VISA) and nfc module. All worked fine, but at a one time I start to get response 65 81 - Memory failure (unsuccessful writing) on my request:

```
00 A4 04 00 07 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 00
```

Is it possibly that I was lock my card? If it is, how I can unlock it? Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possible, but it's hard, you need generate Issuer Script and send it to your card. The issuer script involves a MAC( based on your SMI Session Key) and a Cryptogram( based on SMC Session Key).

Comment: thanks for answer, and how to generate Issuer Script?...